# Setting all faces UV bound to the image texture

Tags: modeling, uv

This mesh is composed of separated faces. How to UV unwrap it so that each face vertices (tri or quad) are bound to the texture corners (respectively as a tri or quad) ? By script or by a shorter solution ?

If needed, I am ok to remake the model or another model to obtain the result.

[image]

Comment: Try **Reset** in **Unwrap** menu

Comment: Would *Reset* option give the [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sEwan.gif) you are looking for? I'm not sure I fully understood if you need faces undeformed...

Comment: Great ! "reset" (as you both said) seems to work very well... thank you